# Does Solidity pre-compute the powers of two defined in the body of functions?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, gas, optimization

I'm using the powers of two in only one my contract functions, but I defined them at the top-level thinking that this way I would save gas at runtime.

Is that necessary though? Can I do the following and incur the same gas cost when using the Solidity optimizer?

```
function foo(uint256 x) external returns (uint256 result) {
    if (x >= 2**128) {
        // ...
    }

    if (x >= 2**64) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, it does cache the numbers, even without the optimizer enabled!

When passing 65535 (max uint16) as the parameter x, it costs 1003 gas to run either `foo` or `bar`. I ran this test with Solidity v0.8.3 on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/).

```
contract PowersOfTwo {
    uint256 internal constant TWO_POW_1 = 2**1;
    uint256 internal constant TWO_POW_2 = 2**2;
    uint256 internal constant TWO_POW_4 = 2**4;
    uint256 internal constant TWO_POW_8 = 2**8;

    function foo(uint16 x) external view returns(uint256 gasConsumed) {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        uint256 msb = 0;
        if (x >= TWO_POW_8) {
            x >>= 8;
            msb += 8;
        }
        if (x >= TWO_POW_4) {
            x >>= 4;
            msb += 4;
        }
        if (x >= TWO_POW_2) {
            x >>= 2;
            msb += 2;
        }
        if (x >= TWO_POW_1) {
            msb += 1;
        }
        gasConsumed = startGas - gasleft();
    }
    
    function bar(uint16 x) external view returns(uint256 gasConsumed) {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        uint256 msb = 0;
        if (x >= 2**8) {
            x >>= 8;
            msb += 8;
        }
        if (x >= 2**4) {
            x >>= 4;
            msb += 4;
        }
        if (x >= 2**2) {
            x >>= 2;
            msb += 2;
        }
        if (x >= 2**1) {
            msb += 1;
        }
        gasConsumed = startGas - gasleft();
    }   
}
```